# Mesh Smoothing My Model

Tags: mesh

So I know this has been asked a million times but I am pretty new to Blender and not finding a resolution that works for me. How can I smooth out these ridges in the attached image? I have tried sculpting and modifiers, etc and feel like I am just missing something, so asking for some clear direction to solve this. Basically as you see this is a pig face, and needs to be rounded out and playing with edges, faces, etc is just not working out either. Please help a brother out!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful if you could describe why other solutions didn't work.

Comment: have you tried a subdivision modifier ?

Comment: Hey! Besides playing with faces, verts, edges I have tried using smooth brush in sculpt mode along with a few others to even it all out to no avail. Subdivision modifier as well as LoopTools. I feel there are many ways this could be accomplished but looking for some direction on how to actually do so from someone with some experience.

Comment: Yes and when doing so it ended up breaking other areas of the model by separating along the mirrored edge

Answer (score 1):

If you want to smooth out the whole mesh you can do it by clicking on the mesh, going into the modifiers tab, adding a Subsurface modifier and increase it's value from 1.

On the other hand if you only want to make a certain area smoother I know a couple of other options:

1) In object mode select the mesh, go into Edit Mode, click 2 to use edge selection, select the edges than you want to smooth, press CTRL+B to apply a bevel to them.

2)In object mode select the mesh, go into Edit Mode, press 3 to enable face selection, select the faces you want to smooth, press W to bring up the Specials tab, select subdivide, press 1 to enable vertex selection, press W again and click smooth.

Of these 2 options it's probably best to use the first one to keep better topology.